# Invalid Method Declaration - Return type required

Tags: java, android

Having issues with the line I labelled. Tried multiple different suggestions but none seem to fix the issue, anyone has anymore suggestions?

```
package connect2you.com;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    findViewById(R.id.textViewSignup).setOnClickListener(this); // error on this line

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.textViewSignup:

                startActivity(new Intent(this, SignUpActivity.class));

                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `findViewById(R.id.textViewSignup).setOnClickListener(this);` - that line of code needs to be inside method in this case `onCreate()`

Answer (score 1):

Put your call tob`findViewById()` inside a method. You can't run code outside of methods.